# Change font size in project file tree in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I was able to change the rest of the IDE's fonts (i.e. menus, dialogs, etc.) by using the "override default fonts" fields in the IDE Settings/Appearance screen of the Settings dialog. But it doesn't seem to affect the font size of the folder/file tree in the left navbar. The default font there is so small I can barely read it. How can I change that font?

UPDATE: I also apparently cannot change the font in the editor. 
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Font in the tree [was not configurable in older versions](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-69802). In the recent versions it should work  using the [configuration](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/1410/20130426203125.png) in `Settings | Appearance`.

To change the editor font use the [Save As...](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/7527/20130426203248.png) button as you can't modify the default scheme.

Comment: Thanks, but as I said, I've tried using the Settings/Appearance tab. It changes the font in the menus and dialogs, but not the file tree. I'm using 6.0, which is the newest version available for Windows. But your instructions did allow me to change the editor font, so thank you for that.

Comment: Update to [6.0.2](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program) and restart PhpStorm after changing the font.

Comment: According to that link, 6.0.2 has a limited 30-day license.

Comment: Don't worry, release version or a new EAP will become available before that, you can also always revert to the latest release build if EAP expires.

Answer (score 6):

For 2017/2018 versions of PHPStorm it's under menu item *PHPStorm > Preferences > Appearance & Behaviour > Apperance > Override default fonts by*. Here you can change the font and the font size.